# Where a function is required, typescript allows me to pass an object with an incompatible `apply` property

Tags: typescript-typings

Currently using typescript **3.4.5** with `strict` mode enabled...

## Backstory

I just ran into a situation where typescript failed to protect me from my own mistakes, unfortunately. And I'm trying to figure out why typescript failed to catch this error.

I was writing a type declaration for a function like this:

```js
function acceptVisitors (visitor) {
    visitor.apply(value);
}
```

Astute observers may point out that `visitor`'s type could be defined in one of two ways — as a function, or as an object with an `apply` property:

```js
type visitorType = (this: IValue) => void;
// or
type visitorType = {
    apply: (value: IValue) => void;
};
```

It turns out, in my case it was the latter. After adding the type declaration, I proceeded to write this incorrect code:

```js
// This is incorrect because it doesn't pass it as an argument.
// Rather, the `this` context is set to the value.
acceptVisitors((value: IValue) => { ... });
```

Now, the puzzling thing is that Typescript did not show an error when I passed a function whose type was incompatible with `visitorType`.

## Simplified example

Let's change the parameter type to a string, and walk through it.
I'm defining a type called `func` that is a function that requires a string argument.

```js
type func = (param1: string) => void;
```

Functions by nature are callable objects that also have an apply method.

```js
declare let f: func;
f.apply(undefined, ['str']);
// all good
```

Now here's the other type — an object with an `apply` property.

```js
type objectWithApplyProp = {
    apply: (param1: string) => void;
};
```

We can call the apply property, but not in the same way...

```js
declare let o: objectWithApplyProp;
o.apply(undefined, ['str']); // Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
```

And `objectWithApplyProp` has a call signature that doesn't work with `func`:

```js
o.apply('str'); // ok
f.apply('str'); // Error: The 'this' context of type 'func' is not assignable to 
                // method's 'this' of type '(this: string) => void'
```

And further tests show that `f` is assignable to `o`, but not the other way around, which makes sense... all functions are objects but not all objects are callable.

But why is `f` considered assignable to `o`? The type of `objectWithApplyProp` requires an `apply` value that matches a *certain type*, and `func` doesn't match it

A function's `apply` signature should be inferrable from its parameters, but typescript doesn't seem to be inferring it.

So, any feedback is welcome. Am I wrong, or is there a limitation in Typescript? Is it a known issue? Thanks

Comment: Relevant: [Strict bind, call, and apply methods on functions #27028](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028), [bind(), call(), and apply() are untyped #212](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212)

Comment: If you rename `apply` in `objectWithApplyProp` to `myApply`, does the whole thing make sense to you then?

Comment: Naming an object method `apply` just make it coincidenctally same as the default method `apply` of all function. That doesn't mean TS should magically understand you want this custom `apply` method behave like the default one. You name it `apply` or `myApply` or `foobar`, its just a name, name doesn't have magic.

Comment: Hi @hackape, unfortunately I can't just rename the object's `apply` property to something else. This is an existing JS code base and I'm just trying to write types for it. And it sounds like you understood my situation backwards -- I don't want the two applies to behave the same. I can't change either one. They are not the same, and I'm just wondering why TypeScript doesn't detect that like it does with other interfaces.

Comment: Ah sorry, i misunderstood. Well, I think the most elegant solution is to wait for 3.5, their [iteration plan](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30555) has [negated type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) on the list. When it ships, you can use constraint like `extends not Function`

Answer (score 0):

So this is a technical reason of why it's happening, and a workaround:

Typescript's built-in [lib/es5.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/454b4280b/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L252) declaration file defines `Function.apply` with parameters of type `any`. Also it defines `Function.prototype` as `any`.

```js
interface Function {
    apply(this: Function, thisArg: any, argArray?: any): any;
    call(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
    bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
    toString(): string;
    prototype: any;
    readonly length: number;
    // Non-standard extensions
    arguments: any;
    caller: Function;
}
```

And I guess all function expressions are given the `Function` type by default.

So the function was allowed to be assigned to the object with the incompatible `apply` property because the function did not have a strongly typed `apply` method, based on the built-in `Function` types. Therefore typescript could not determine that the `apply` signatures were different.

[Typescript 3.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-32) introduces [CallableFunction](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/454b4280b/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L308) which has generic arguments on its `apply` declaration. But I haven't figured out how to make it fix this problem.

A workaround is to define a stronger function type and manually assign it to the function. The workaround is a bit tedious, but it works.

```js
interface func extends Function {
    (param1: string): void;
    // manually define `apply
    apply<T, R> (thisArg: T, args: [string]): R;
}
interface objectWithApplyProp { // unchanged
    apply: (param1: string) => void;
}
// Now we have proper errors here:
o = f;
// Type 'func' is not assignable to type 'objectWithApplyProp'.
//  Types of property 'apply' are incompatible.
//    Type '<T, R>(thisArg: T, args: [string]) => R' is not assignable to type '(param1: string) => void'. ts(2322)
f = o;
// Type 'objectWithApplyProp' is missing the following properties from type 'func': call, bind, prototype, length, and 2 more. ts(2740)
```